# What does this part taken from the text below mean?

Tags: word-meaning

Australia, which is coordinating the search in the southern Indian Ocean, said it had **established** a new **body** to oversee the investigation and issued countries involved in the search a set of protocols to abide by should any wreckage be found.
..................

I am wondering if my perception is correct?

My perception: ** it had stablished a new body to oversee the investigation and issued countries involved in the search a set of protocols to abide by should any wreckage be found** really means " it had **determined** a new **boss** to oversee the investigation and issued countries involved in the search a set of rules to be obeyed if any wreckage would be found.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Established", set up, created a new "body" organized group of people,

"To abide by' to conform to the set rules.

Comment: -Thanks a million. I would be greatful if you tell my what the word SHOULD in the text mean? I forgat to ask it then. Does it mean "if" here?

Comment: Should any wreckage be found means  in case any wreckage is found. Should is always followed be the infinite of a verb without "to".

Answer (score 2):

### Establish

> <sub>[From google "define: XXX, definition 1"](https://www.google.com.ph/search?q=define%3a%20establish&rlz=1C1CHMO_enPH532PH532&oq=define%3a%20establish&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i58.3885j0j1&sourceid=chrome&espv=2&es_sm=93&ie=UTF-8)</sub>
>
> to `set up` (an organization, system, or set of rules) on a firm or permanent basis

### Body

> <sub>[From google "define: XXX, definition 3"](https://www.google.com.ph/search?q=define%3a%20establish&rlz=1C1CHMO_enPH532PH532&oq=define%3a%20body&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i58.3885j0j1&sourceid=chrome&espv=2&es_sm=93&ie=UTF-8#q=define%3a+body)</sub>
>
> a `group of people with a common purpose` or function acting as an
>   organized unit.

### Therefore: "establish a body"

> "...**set-up** a **group of people** to oversee the investigation..."